# Accessing specific sheets named with number and a word

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to set up a loop copying and pasting given range of the sheet. It is supposed to do the same thing for multiple sheets which are named as given: `1 [RSX]`, `2 [RSX]`, and so on.

I was trying to get the right name of the sheet with the formula, but it doesn't work: `spreadsheet.getSheetByName(i + " " + addition).showSheet()`

All of the code below:

```
function koniec_dnia_gokarty() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var addition = "[RSX]"

  for (var i=1;i<23;i++) {
  spreadsheet.getSheetByName(i + " " + addition).showSheet()
  .activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName(i + " " + addition), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('H1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('O2:O100').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('H101').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('O101:O201').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().hideSheet();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
function lfunko() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ss.getSheets().forEach((sh,i) => {
     let idx = sh.getName().indexOf("[RSX]");
     if(~idx) {
       sh.getRange("O2:O100").copyTo(sh.getRange("H1"));
       sh.getRange("O101:O201").copyTo(sh.getRange("H101"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false)
       sh.hideSheet();
     }
  })
}
```